# Does WGET timeout?

Tags: linux, cron, wget

I'm running a PHP script via cron using Wget, with the following command:

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/cron/run
```

The script will take a maximum of 5-6 minutes to do its processing. Will WGet wait for it and give it all the time it needs, or will it time out?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

According to [the man page of wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options), there are a couple of options related to timeouts -- and there is a default read timeout of 900s -- so I say that, yes, it could timeout.

Here are the options in question :

```
-T seconds
--timeout=seconds
```

> Set the network timeout to seconds
>   seconds.  This is equivalent to
>   specifying `--dns-timeout`,
>   `--connect-timeout`, and
>   `--read-timeout`, all at the same
>   time.

And for those three options :

```
--dns-timeout=seconds
```

> Set the DNS lookup timeout to seconds
>   seconds.  
> DNS lookups that don't
>   complete within the specified time
>   will fail. 
> By default, there is no
>   timeout on DNS lookups, other than
>   that implemented by system libraries.

```
--connect-timeout=seconds
```

> Set the connect timeout to seconds
>   seconds. 
> TCP connections that take
>   longer to establish will be aborted.
>   
> By default, there is no connect
>   timeout, other than that implemented
>   by system libraries.

```
--read-timeout=seconds
```

> Set the read (and write) timeout to
>   seconds seconds. 
> The "time" of
>   this timeout refers to idle time: if,
>   at any point in the download, no data
>   is received for more than the
>   specified number of seconds, reading
>   fails and the download is restarted.
>   
> This option does not directly
>   affect the duration of the entire
>   download.

I suppose using something like

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 --timeout=600 http://www.example.com/cron/run
```

should make sure there is no timeout before longer than the duration of your script.

*(Yeah, that's probably the most brutal solution possible ^^ )*

Comment: if i set -t 0 will it wait indefinitely?

Comment: The `-t` option seems to be an alias of `--tries`, which *Set number of retries to number.* ;;; It doesn't seem to relate to any kind of timeout, but to the number of times wget will re-try to download if there is an error -- and you probably don't want a timeout be considered as an error, and the script being re-called.

Comment: --timeout=0 will disable timeout

Comment: i'm probably the one on the planet but for ubuntu 16 wget just ignores values for `--timeout`. Probably because I'm using basic auth in the command

Answer (score 44):

The default timeout is 900 second. You can specify different timeout.

```
-T seconds
--timeout=seconds
```

The default is to retry 20 times. You can specify different tries.

```
-t number
--tries=number
```

link: [wget man document](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

Answer (score 8):

Prior to version 1.14, wget timeout arguments were not adhered to if downloading over https due to a [bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=20523).

Comment: Damn! CentOS 6 ships with wget 1.12, I got the same issue with https links

Comment: I'm having the exact same error! Wget stopped at https link which has expired certificate !

Comment: I have a Linux with a wget version 1.20.3 which also ignores "-T x" and never terminates on a wrong IP for example, which is why I use the "timeout" comand instead: "timeout 5 wget ..." works perfectly in my case.

Answer (score 7):

Since in your question you said it's a PHP script, maybe the best solution could be to simply add in your script:

```
ignore_user_abort(TRUE);
```

In this way even if `wget` terminates, the PHP script goes on being processed at least until it does not exceeds `max_execution_time` limit (ini directive: 30 seconds by default).

As per `wget` anyay you should not change its timeout, [according to the UNIX manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wget) **the default wget timeout is 900 seconds (15 minutes)**, whis is much larger that the 5-6 minutes you need.

Answer (score 3):

**None of the wget timeout values have anything to do with how long it takes to download a file.**

If the PHP script that you're triggering sits there idle for 5 minutes and returns no data, wget's `--read-timeout` will trigger if it's set to less than the time it takes to execute the script.

If you are actually downloading a file, or if the PHP script sends some data back, like a ... progress indicator, then the read timeout won't be triggered as long as the script is doing something.

`wget --help` tells you:

```
  -T,  --timeout=SECONDS           set all timeout values to SECONDS
       --dns-timeout=SECS          set the DNS lookup timeout to SECS
       --connect-timeout=SECS      set the connect timeout to SECS
       --read-timeout=SECS         set the read timeout to SECS
```

So if you use `--timeout=10` it sets the timeouts for DNS lookup, connecting, and reading bytes to 10s.

When downloading files you can set the timeout value pretty low and as long as you have good connectivity to the site you're connecting to you can still download a large file in 5 minutes with a 10s timeout. If you have a temporary connection failure to the site or DNS, the transfer will time out after 10s and then retry (if `--tries` aka `-t` is > 1).

For example, here I am downloading a file from NVIDIA that takes 4 minutes to download, and I have wget's timeout values set to 10s:

```
$ time wget --timeout=10 --tries=1 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.2.2/local_installers/cuda_11.2.2_460.32.03_linux.run
--2021-07-02 16:39:21--  https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.2.2/local_installers/cuda_11.2.2_460.32.03_linux.run
Resolving developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)... 152.195.19.142
Connecting to developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)|152.195.19.142|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3057439068 (2.8G) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘cuda_11.2.2_460.32.03_linux.run.1’

cuda_11.2.2_460.32.03_linux.run.1        100%[==================================================================================>]   2.85G  12.5MB/s    in 4m 0s

2021-07-02 16:43:21 (12.1 MB/s) - ‘cuda_11.2.2_460.32.03_linux.run.1’ saved [3057439068/3057439068]


real    4m0.202s
user    0m5.180s
sys 0m16.253s
```

4m to download, timeout is 10s, everything works just fine.

In general, timing out DNS, connections, and reads using a low value is a good idea. If you leave it at the default value of 900s you'll be waiting 15m every time there's a hiccup in DNS or your Internet connectivity.