# Execute jsp via Wget and close connection

Tags: bash, jsp, batch-file, cmd, wget

Please help me. 
I need to execute jsp file via Wget. But jsp will be executing very long time. I need run jsp, **don't waiting** when it will be done and close connection (for example, 1 minute after start executing jsp file). 
How I can do thise? Maybe wget have some options or bash/batch commands can help me?

Comment: Or Wget don't waiting when jsp will be done?

Comment: can you elaborate. Maybe you can use & at the end. For Eg:

ssh -q user@hostname wget http://localhost:8080/context/page.jsp &

Comment: Please see if it's the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291524/does-wget-timeout

Comment: Note: `batch-file` does **not** mean processing batches of files.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for All!

Resolve my problem by adding two options:
**--timeout=123** and **--tries=1**

Now Wget connecting to server, waiting 123 seconds and disconnect. Attention! Wget send error. In batch script use, for example, "exit 0".