# Wget Timeout if download takes too long

Tags: linux, wget

Is there any way to stop a`wget`download if the download is not completed in x seconds?
For example if in 2 seconds the download is not complete, to get a timeout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does WGET timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291524/does-wget-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

[`wget`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) has following timeout related options

```
--timeout=seconds
--dns-timeout=seconds 
--connect-timeout=seconds
--read-timeout=seconds
```

see linked man page for explanation.

> Is there any way to stop a`wget`download if the download is not
> completed in x seconds?

You might find [`timeout`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) command useful, it does kill provided command if it does not end in given amount of seconds. For example

```
timeout 5 wget https://www.example.com
```

does give 5 seconds wget to download [example](https://www.example.com/) and if it fails to do kill it. Note that `timeout` command might be used with other commands that `wget`.